# NullPointerException in Threads

Tags: java

**Why am I getting NullPointerException here**

```
package Threads;

public class Test implements Runnable {

      FF d;

     public static void main(String[] args) {

          new Test().go();

       }

      void go() {

         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
         d = new FF();
         new Thread(new Test()).start();
         new Thread(new Test()).start();
      }

      public void run() {

         System.out.println(d);
         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
         d.chat(Thread.currentThread().getId());//RTE
     }

}

class FF {

    static long flag = 0;

      void chat(long id) {

           if(flag == 0) {

              flag = id;

           }
           for(int x=1;x<3;x++) {

               if(flag == id) {

                   System.out.println("Yo");

               }else {

                   System.out.println("dude");

                }
           }
     } 
}
```

//can anybody explain why I am getting NullPointerException here.I though `d` reference variable was intialized in `go()` method but I think it has something to do when new Thread is created.

Comment: What does the stack trace say? You're supposed to read it to understand what the problem is. And to post it if you can't understand it.

Comment: Your thinking is correct. Who initializes `d`? The `go()` method? Is that called in the two lines that create new threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`d` is an instance field for class `Test`. Initializing it for one instance of `Test` does not make it initialized for all instances that are subsequently created. You have initialized this field in the `go` method of the instance you create in `main`. But after that, you create *new* instances of `Test` for which their field is not initialized yet:

```
new Thread(new Test()).start();   // d is not initialized for the new Test() object
new Thread(new Test()).start();
```

One solution is to initialize the field in the constructor:

```
public Test() {
    d = new FF();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you're creating a new Test instance and thus d is not initialized (since the thread.start method doesn't call your go method but only the run method).